# Noun for an experience you went through with others

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I asked a similar question before, about what to call a group of people that went through the same class, semester of a program, club, spent a week cruising with each other, etc.

But what I want to know is, a word that captures that all of you went through the same ____________.

I'm building an app and I need this as a general term to denote the organized experience you went through together. It's part of an organized program, probably a section of it, recurring. It's going to be used quite often throughout the app once I select one. So I'm soliciting ideas.

Just to give you some terms we already use:

- Community - refers to any sort of community, e.g. students and alumni of a university, or neighbors in a building, or people who are taking / have taken a cruise, etc.
- Group - a group of people that forms on demand to do some activity, e.g. go get some sushi, watch a movie, take a trip, etc. You can join a group or start a group.

So this term would join the others, to denote a "subcommunity" of people that went through the same experience, organized by some organization.

To give you more context, this is our product: http://qbix.com/communities

Comment: "***Journey***" is increasingly used to describe this kind of *shared experience*, particularly when the experience has been challenging and led to some kind of learning or personal growth.  You'd say "Went **on** the same journey" rather than "through the same journey".

Comment: What about "circle"? as in circle of friends, a circle of initiates or a *sharing circle*.

Comment: Not sure, but how about [*emotional contagion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_contagion)? It means a process in which a person or group influences the emotions or behavior of another person or group through the conscious or unconscious induction of emotion states and behavioral attitudes.

Comment: *Happening*, *event*, *experience*,...

Comment: I think "shared experience" fits your meaning pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Two that spring to mind are ***a collective experience*** and a ***mutual experience***.

*All of us went through the same **collective/mutual** experience*.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are nouns for different forms of shared experiences such as dalliance and collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

> All of us went through the same ____________.
>
> All of us went through the same *shared experience*.

That means we have a shared bond.

Answer (score 0):

> It's part of an organized program, probably a section of it, recurring.

As you specify that each experience is part of a program perhaps [episode](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/episode) will best describe them.